# Can I filter a list view web part based on the ID of an Asset Library properties item?

Tags: list-view, 2016, connection-filters

SP OnPrem 2016:

In other applications I have successfully connected list forms and list view web parts to filter the results by ID. The concept is pretty simple.

Now I need to do the same but using an Asset Library properties item as the Source of the ID.  From the list view when I try: `Connections - Get Filter Values From - My Assets Library`, the `"Configure Connections"` box pops up but it's empty and I can't do anything. There are no options to choose.

I tried the same thing in reverse, starting from the Asset Library form and setting up the connection.  I get the same results.

Same results in Chrome and IE11.

If I set up a QueryString filter the connection process works, but it doesn't solve my specific situation.

So I'm thinking there's some kind of restriction on connecting list view web parts to Asset Libraries, or perhaps with any kind of Document Library.

Can anybody confirm this?

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Asset libraries are not ordinary libraries. When files are uploaded, a folder is created with the file's name. The file is then stored in this folder. There is also additional automation to create thumbnails, etc.

So, what you see in Asset libraries are folders, and web part connections don't work with folders. That said, it's interesting that you got query string filters to work!

See:
https://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2015/05/sharepoint-2013-asset-library-secrets.html

Comment: Thanks Mike. That makes sense and your blog post has a lot of great info.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved:**

I was able to get the Query String Filter to do what I needed. The goal was to show related items that matched the ID of the Asset. Using the Query String Filter allowed me to grab the ID and I could connect that to my list view web part. Now it filters properly.